# IOS/autolayout: Detect touch event below visible view of scrollview

Tags: ios, autolayout, scrollview

I have been struggling with how to detect touches on a portion of a tall textview subview that extends below the visible view of a screen.

The view hierarchy looks like this:
View Controller
UIView (UV,visible portion of screen)
  UIScrollView (SV)
    UIView (CV,Content View--contains all elements)
      UITextView (TV)

When the screen first loads, a portion of the textview (TV) is visible, the portion contained within the UV, or visible portion of the screen. When you scroll, you move the scrollview (SV) behind the visible portion of screen, revealing portions of the textview that are outside the original UIView (UV).

When you scroll down, while you can see the lower portions of the textview, they do not respond to touches.

Can anyone suggest a way to make an entire textview reponsive to touches even, portions of the textview that extend below the visible UIVIew?

Do I need to make UIVIew (visible portion of screen) bigger than the actual phone screen?  Or what can I do.

Of note, the gesture recognizer is currently added to the view in viewdidload before views are laid out.  It does adjust to changes in the view size based on quantity of text up to the UIView (UV) edge.  However, it will not recognize touches below the original UV bottom edge.

Thanks for any suggestions.

In visual debugger, you can see the UIView in white and the scrollview in blue.  The portion of the textview that is white--equivalent to what you see before scrolling--is touchable, while the portion in blue, visible after scrolling, is not.

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? It's hard to visualize the view hierarchy

Comment: See picture from visual debugger above.  The UIImageview between uppermost UIView and UIScrollview is inserted by the system--something to do with how the scrollview works.  The top UIView corresponds to the visible window, and the UIView between ScrollView and UILabel is the Content View.  The blue is the scrollview.  The portion of the textview above the blue at the bottom does not respond to touches.